# How to avoid hardcoded url in Axis generated code?

Tags: java, maven, axis

The project I maintain uses the axis-maven-plugin for generating source code. This source code is used for calling a PDF generator service.

However the url to the service is hard coded in the generated Java code.

```
public class GenerateReportServServiceLocator
             extends org.apache.axis.client.Service
             implements com.company.GenerateReportServService
{
    // ... 

    // Use to get a proxy class for GenerateReportServ
    private java.lang.String GenerateReportServ_address =
    /* Hardcoded URL */   "http://host:port/PdfEngine/GenerateReportServ.jws";

   // ...
}
```

How can I tell axis-maven-plugin to use our properties configuration file for finding the url ?

Here is the pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <urls>
           <url>http://host:port/PdfEngine/GenerateReportServ.jws</url>
        </urls>
        <packageSpace>com.company.project.core.pdf.engine</packageSpace>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies> 
      // ...
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-ws-service-impression</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is this to make the endpoint configurable at runtime? Why not just provide a utility type that sets the endpoint on the port before provisioning the service client?

Comment: @McDowell Actually, in the code generated by Axis the url is hardcoded in many other places. If the application goes to production and the W$ moves (ie its url changes), then the application must be recompiled AND redeployed to production. This eludes the **properties file advantage**. I'm facing two options either carefully configure the classes generated by Axis or create a custom class that inherits from Axis classes for adding the missing **environment independence**. Either way, that's just PAINFULL !

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? By the way, I think this is an Axis issue, as I get the same result both with [Axis Tools Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/) and by running `wsdl2java` from the Axis 1.4 binary package.

Comment: @watery Please see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343397/363573.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any option from Axis for avoiding this problem. As a result, I decided to rewrite the code that was generated by Axis previously.

Chance for me, I needed to write only few classes. My code is now environment independant.